# Is this the correct way for storing a sub-collection?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a users collection and from there I wanted to have a sub-collection about the vaccination info of the specific user. This is how I save the sub-collection inside the user's collections.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const userRef = firestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(uid)
        .collection("vaccination")
        .doc();
      const ref = userRef.set(
        {
          vaccineType,
          firstDoseDate,
          secDoseDate,
          firstVaccinator,
          secondVaccinator,
        },
        { merge: true }
      );

      console.log(" saved");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

This is what it looks like in firestore:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If a user can have only 2 doses then it'll make sense to store it in the user doc itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way to create a subcollection, but note that you do not need the `merge` option here. `merge` is used when you are updating an existing document and don't want to fully overwrite it. In your case, you're not passing an existing subcollection doc id so `set` will create a new document and there's nothing to merge.

You also need to `await` the `set` function as it returns a promise that you need to `await` for it to resolve.

```js
// This creates a new document and you don't need {merge: true}
const newDocRef = firestore
  .collection("users")
  .doc(uid)
  .collection("vaccination")
  .doc();
const newDoc = await newDocRef.set({
  vaccineType,
  firstDoseDate,
  secDoseDate,
  firstVaccinator,
  secondVaccinator,
});

// This updates an existing document, in which case you might want
// {merge: true} if you don't want to overwrite the entire document
// but just want to write/update the fields in the set call.
const existingDocRef = firestore
  .collection("users")
  .doc(uid)
  .collection("vaccination")
  .doc(vaccinationDocId);
const updatedExistingDoc = await existingDocRef.set({
  vaccineType,
  firstDoseDate,
  secDoseDate,
  firstVaccinator,
  secondVaccinator,
}, { merge: true });
```

Comment: what if I have a form to save in the firestore, but then I also need the form to update the data in the firestore?